# How to speed up query which is using <@> operator?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using `earthdistance` extension (along with `cube` extension).

I have following query:

```
SELECT "User"."id"
    ,"User"."displayName"
    ,"User"."firstName"
    ,"User"."lastName"
    ,"User"."email"
    ,("User".position <@> Point(45, 45)) AS distance
FROM "Users" AS "User"
WHERE (("User".position <@> Point(45, 45)) <= 621.371192)
ORDER BY distance ASC
    ,"User"."id" ASC LIMIT 25;
```

Here is explain/analyze http://explain.depesz.com/s/61pp
I am using `Postgres 9.3`.

I have created `GIST` index on `position` column (which is of type `point` but it is not used by query (I am querying across 50k rows):

```
CREATE INDEX users_position_index
ON "Users"
USING gist
("position");
```

Comment: Are you using a keyword (that is exactly 1 character shorter than the table name and altogether unnecessary)  as a table alias out of masochism? ;)  At the same time, is a query running for a whopping 32 **ms** really too slow?

Comment: This is sql generated by ORM. You, database administrators, should finally understand that SQL databases are not only for executing raw queries written by hand :). As for performance, I just want to be sure it is best as it can be - so I want my query to use index...

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `<@>` operator but the expression basically boils down to `table.somepoint - someconstantpoint <= someconstantdistance`, correct? I guess in order to make it sargable, you'd need to invert it to an equivalent of `table.somepoint <= someconstantpoint + someconstantdistance`. Not sure but maybe the [`earth_box()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/earthdistance.html) and [`<@` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-geometry.html) are what you need here, as in `"User".position <@ earth_box(Point(45, 45), 621.371192)`.

Comment: @user606521 OK, but you ORM users should state this before we DBAs jump on it ;)

Comment: @user606521: That's like telling a French person that he should *"finally understand that he must not expect proper French in his conversations, but gibberish from Google translate is equally valid"*. It's the other way round: ORM users must understand that ORMs are crude crutches that are popular with lazy developers trying to avoid learning SQL. Fair enough, I am lazy, too. But don't turn it around on us. To use the full potential of your RDBMS, you need to speak the native language, which is SQL. Your ORM is doing a poor job. Besides, "SQL database" is a misnomer. SQL is a query language.

Comment: Can it be that you are using the additional module [earthdistance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/earthdistance.html) without mentioning it?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, I forgot to mention it - edited post. And without ORM maintaining big project is a nightmare - not an option for me. I agree that ORMs are not ideal, and it is often neccessery to use some workarounds to make things work, but without ORM it would be  a lot harder.

Comment: @user606521 arguably being able to tune your database queries is MORE important on a big project, is it not?

Comment: @JNK yes, that's exactly what I am doing - tuning ORM queries where it is needed :). But I can't agree that ORMs are a bad thing.

Comment: @user606521: Nobody said *that*.